# Sometimes give me Skipped 57 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: php, android, image

i have this code for send image from android to server, and it works!
But sometimes it give me back an error in logcat:

```
Skipped 57 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread
```

But i don t know only sometimes and for example, the phone where is installed this app don t work well when this happen!

```
public class SendingImage extends Activity {

        private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE = 100;   

        TextView tvPath;
        TextView txtHaut;
        ImageView preview;
        File destination;
        String imagePath;
        ImageButton takePhoto;
        Button btnCreate;

        int serverResponseCode = 0;
        ProgressDialog dialog = null;

        String upLoadServerUri = null;

        String name;       

        private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1;
        private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 2;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sending_image);

            preview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPreview);
            btnCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bInviaFoto) ;
            txtHaut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewEsito);
            takePhoto = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bCamera);
            preview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txtHaut.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            upLoadServerUri = "http://fiezzo.altervista.org/upload_image.php";

            name = dateToString(new Date(),"yyyyMMddhhmmss");
            destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), name + ".jpg");


            takePhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(destination));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);
                }
            }); 


            btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(SendingImage.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {              
                            uploadFile(imagePath);
                        }
                    }).start();        
                }

            }); 



        }


        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if( requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ){
                try {
                    preview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    takePhoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    txtHaut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txtHaut.setText("Immagine selezionata correttamente!");

                    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(destination);
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inSampleSize = 15;
                    imagePath = destination.getAbsolutePath();
                    Log.d("INFO", "PATH === " +imagePath);
                    //tvPath.setText(imagePath);
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
                    preview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            else{
                tvPath.setText("Request cancelled");
            }
        }


        /**
         * open camera method
         */
        public void callCamera() {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            cameraIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
            cameraIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
            cameraIntent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
            cameraIntent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

        }

        /**
         * open gallery method
         */

        public void callGallery() {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
            intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),
                    PICK_FROM_GALLERY);

        }

        public String dateToString(Date date, String format) {
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
            return df.format(date);
        }

        public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

            String fileName = sourceFileUri;

            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;  
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
            File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

            if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
                dialog.dismiss(); 
                Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" +imagePath);
                return 0;
            } else {
                try { 

                    // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                    URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                    // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                    conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename="+ fileName + "" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    // create a buffer of  maximum size
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // read file and write it into form...
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                    while (bytesRead > 0) {

                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                    }

                    // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                    // Responses from the server (code and message)
                    serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                    Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "+ serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                    if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                Toast.makeText(SendingImage.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });                
                    }    

                    //close the streams //
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();

                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                    dialog.dismiss();  
                    ex.printStackTrace();

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            Toast.makeText(SendingImage.this, "MalformedURLException",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    dialog.dismiss();  
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            Toast.makeText(SendingImage.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);  
                }
                dialog.dismiss();   
                return serverResponseCode; 

            } // End else block 
        } 

    }
```

Here is it also the php code:

```
<?php
    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

i m using as example this project:
http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

Thanks a lot for the help or suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're starting a new thread for the upload itself, which is good. But this bit

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
```

is being executed on the main thread. You should think about moving that into the background, so that you're not reading the image in on the main thread. That might be your problem.

More generally, think about using `AsyncTask` for these things: it's much more flexible, and less error-prone, than creating and managing your own threads.

It also has something in place to allow you to do things on the main thread when the background work is done. So with your `Bitmap`, you'd do the loading and the `decodeStream()` call in the `doInBackground()` method, which happens on a background thread; and then the following line

```
preview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

is what you'd do in the `onPostExecute()`, which happens (automatically) on the main thread, because you have to interact with your GUI components on the main thread.

Comment: i tryed it with AsyncTask but it not work dro my version!
Do u have suggestions or help?
Thanks a lot

Comment: @MarcC If you mean that you're using an old version of Android that doesn't have it available, try `CompatAsyncTask` from the Android Support Libs.